NtQueryInformationProcess returns STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS for ProcessInstrumentationCallback
I am trying to get the process instrumentation callback using NtQueryInformationProcess but it keeps returning STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS.
I know that this error means that the ProcessInformationClass argument is invalid but from the google searches I done it looks like ProcessInstrumentationCallback is a real class but just hidden.
here is my code:
#define PROCESS_INSTRUMENTATION_CALLBACK 40

typedef struct
{
    ULONG verision;
    ULONG reserved;
    PVOID callback;
} process_instrumentation_callback_information_t;

process_instrumentation_callback_information_t nirvana;

NTSTATUS status = manual_query_information_process(GetCurrentProcess(), (PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS)PROCESS_INSTRUMENTATION_CALLBACK, &nirvana, sizeof(process_instrumentation_callback_information_t), NULL);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    logger::log("Unable to get callback: 0x%x\n", status);
    return 1;
}
logger::log("Got callback\n");


you can only set ProcessInstrumentationCallback but can not query. you and must got here STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS

so is there no way i can get it in usermode?

dont know. how minimum ProcessInstrumentationCallback design only for set.

I dont think its possible to get the instrumentation callback address from usermode. I just got the address from kernel and stored it as a offset so I can use it in usermode.
